# Is my internship Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, work

Salam. I am a student who needs an internship and it’s hard to get one in my field but for now it looks like I can land a potential internship at Amnesty and they are known for constantly and actively supporting LGBTQ among other haram things. The main reason I want this internship is because they do a lot for the genocide in Palestine when it comes to spreading info and researching, and this is what I wanna work on with them (or other halal Muslim-related problems). An internship is also not payed work so I’m working for free. Is it haram to work here for an internship, or even do payed work (if I ever get a job offer here) if it’s about issues like the Palestinian genocide?

Answer (score 1):

The permissibility of working in such a place is a nuanced issue. My understanding is that your work is considered permissible if:

- Your work or volunteering involves only halal and charitable actions, and you have a clear intention and resolution to avoid promoting or engaging in haram activities.
- The haram activities are a minor part of the company's overall business (it is not what the company is primarily known for).

A useful practical step would be to explain to them the things that you disagree with as a Muslim, and make sure you would not be expected to promote or participate in haram activities as an intern or an employee.

Even then, it is better to seek work in other places which don't involve promoting haram activities and comply fully with islamic principles, and to make du'a to find better alternatives.